# Remainder when $x^{2016}+x^{2013}+\cdots+x^6+x^3$ is divided by $x^2+x+1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I am currently preparing for a certain quiz show when I encountered this question:

What is the remainder when $x^{2016}+x^{2013}+\cdots+x^6+x^3$ is divided by $x^2+x+1$?

I know for a fact that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

And I got

$$x^{2016}+x^{2013}+\cdots+x^6+x^3=x^3(x^{2013}+x^{2010}+\cdots+x^3+1)$$
$$=[(x-1)(x^2+x+1)+1](x^{2013}+x^{2010}+\cdots+x^3+1)$$
$$=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)
(x^{2013}+x^{2010}+\cdots+x^3+1)+(x^{2013}+x^{2010}+\cdots+x^3+1)$$

I know that the remainder comes from the term not containing $x^2+x+1$ but I do not know to get it since it involved so many terms.

Any help please? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As $x^3=1\implies x^{3n}=(x^3)^n=1\implies x^{3n}\equiv1\pmod{x^2+x+1}$

and $2016=3\cdot672$

$$\sum_{r=1}^{672}x^{3r}\equiv\sum_{r=1}^{672}1\pmod{x^2+x+1}$$

Comment: A little bit of number theory, indeed. I thought I can solve with brute force using synthetic division. This may soon come in handy. Thanks!

Comment: @HenrisonCatipanSanchez, You mean divide by $x^3-1$ ?

Comment: Nope. I thought that i'll just have to divide the term not containing $x^2+x+1$ since this is where the remainder should have been.

Comment: @HenrisonCatipanSanchez: It's not number theory, just algebra: $x^3=(x-1)(x^2+x+1) + 1$, so $x^3 \equiv 1 \bmod x^2+x+1$. Hence $x^6\equiv x^3\cdot x^3 \equiv 1\cdot 1 \equiv 1$ etc.

Comment: @TonyK, I mean, the solution does involve modulo operations. I just first encountered it when I read books about number theory. Well anyway, Thank you sir for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{672}x^{3k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{672}\left((x-1)(x^2+x+1)+1\right)^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{672}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}{k \choose j}\left((x-1)(x^2+x+1)\right)^{j}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{672}\left((x^2+x+1)P_k(x)+1\right)\\
&=(x^2+x+1)P(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{672}1
\end{align}